# target framework not showing in visual studio 2019

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

target framework not showing in visual studio 2019. I have installed .Net 4.8 
[image]

Comment: you have created core application that why .Net 4.8 is not showing

Comment: Create a .NET Framework application project

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Create Console App of .Net Framework.

[image]

After creating .Net Framework console app,check properties of app. you will see all the installed .net frameworks.
  [image]